# Only one consumer gets kafka messages with 5 partitions

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We tested consumers group with 2 and 3 consumers (knowing that we may have more consumers in the future) using the confluent kafka package for Go.

With 10 partitions per topic the messages are split between all the consumers.

With 5 partitions per topic somehow only one consumer gets the messages.

Any idea why this behavior?

Comment: Are the messages spread evenly across partitions?

Comment: How can I check this? From my logs it looks like it

Comment: How do you set messages? Do your messages have key set, or it's only value&

Comment: @streetturtle: No we don't use key set.

Comment: You can debug the assignment process by setting the `debug` property to `cgrp`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this command to see the partition assignments, and add the results here?
`bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <your-broker-ip>:9092 --describe --group <your-consumer-group> --members --verbose`

By default, Kafka uses range partitioning scheme, so sometimes there are unexpected behaviors (e.g. if you have only one partition per topic, and multiple consumers, only one consumer will be assigned to all the partitions). I don't know if that's relevant here, but you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51703503/consumer-group-member-has-no-partition/51704869#51704869) post for more detail.

Comment: Honestly we dropped kafka and ended up using nats.